# Python [ ] notation in list

Tags: python, list

There's a list as follows: `list = []`.

and then assuming `x = 'A'`, what does `list = list + [x]` mean? Is that only for characters? If so, how can it be adapted for integers?

Comment: I am *sure* this is covered in the tutorial *and* on other SO questions ..

Comment: And no, that reasoning is easily disproved: `list = []; list = list + [42]`

Comment: It is explained elsewhere. At least the individual components are. If you, Darksky, have problems with the specific combination, please explain what you know so we can build on that.

Comment: Do you think I really haven't looked for it before asking the question? I've searched for quite a while and the results are not even catching the [] properly, or yielding a useful/relevant result.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

`lis=lis+[x]` means add `'a'` to `[]` and then store the new list `['a']` in `lis` on the LHS

but doing it this way creates new object everytime:

```
In [38]: x='a'

In [39]: lis=[]

In [40]: id(lis)
Out[40]: 154680492

In [41]: lis=lis+[x]

In [42]: lis
Out[42]: ['a']

In [43]: id(lis)
Out[43]: 154749100
```

Better use `lis+=[x]` or `lis.extend(x)`

Comment: "[S]tore the new list in lis" is incorrect, as you're neither putting it _into_ the list `lis` is pointing to or rebinding `lis` to point at your new list. You're _appending_ the new list to the existing list held in `lis`.

Answer (score 4):

First, use a different name instead of `list`.

Then, just try it. You have a Python shell, right?

```
>>> l = []
>>> l = l + "a"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
>>> l = l + ["a"]
>>> l
['a']
>>> l = l + [1]
>>> l
['a', 1]
>>> l = l + 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's concatenate of lists with any data:

```
>>> [1, "a", True] + ["hello", 2.3]
[1, "a", True, "hello", 2.3]
```